# Evaluate a condition BEFORE put() in NDB and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have a model in my GAE based application, which is being updated quite frequently. And in some cases, it happens that same entity is being updated nearly at the same time. The entity update functionality in the app works like that:

1. User enters an ID and other properties of the entity which are to be updated.
2. Retrieve entity from DB against this ID (to make sure ID was valid).
3. Do bunch of validation on the properties which are going to be updated (e.g. if group_id property is being updated then make sure group is present in DB against this ID and ID is integer.)
4. After validations, call put() on the entity which was retrieved at step #2.

As, i mentioned same entity can be updated multiple times nearly at the same time, so i came across the classical race condition issue. i.e. let's say 2 update calls were made sequentially, in first call entity was retrieved and validations were in process but, at the same time second call triggered it retrieves the same and updates it properties. The second call also executes put() and update entity in DB. NOTE that first call was not completed yet (due to some time delay), it completes now and calls put() and updates entity in DB.

The end result in DB will be off first update call, but expected result was of second call!

I researched on GAE about this and found pre-put hooks. I think i can use "updated" timestamps to solve this issue i.e. to make sure second call only updates an entity after first call does it. But, i want to use some better approach here e.g. some DB's (like in AWS) provide tags with each DB row and we can ask DB itself to validate this tag before actually putting the record. I am curious as is there any way in GAE to do so. i.e. to ask DB to do conditional put() instead of using pre_put hooks manually?

Comment: Check out transactions in GAE.  This is what you need.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill I checked it already and learned that it is using "Optimistic Concurrency Control". You are right, this is what i need. But, transactions has their own limitations which i would like to avoid. That's why i am looking for doing it in a way other than transactions.

Comment: Maybe use the SQL database instead of datastore.  Implementing your own locking mechanism is not an easy thing to do...